# При выводе в шаблон с помощью расширения lavare/laravel-menu из таблицы БД дочерние пункты меню подвязываются не к тем, что надо основным пунктам меню

Tags: laravel

Исходники: https://github.com/Oleg2015/corporate.loc

Результат выборки из таб. menus БД в $menu правильный - коллекция объектов модели Menu (записей в таб. menus), id и parent=3 дочерних пунктов соответствует табличным.
А после создания объекта $mBuilder (т.е. самого меню) класса Builder расширения lavary/laravel-menu дочерние пункты имеют parent=1 и выводятся в шаблон, как подпункты первого основного пункта меню, а должны быть привязаны ко второму !!!

Заранее всем благодарен ??!!!

Answer (score 0):

Причина не в коде, а в том, что в свойстве (столбце таблицы menus) parent для дочерних пунктов меню необходимо указывать значение свойства id того родительского пункта, к которому подвязываются данные дочернние пункты !!